# Is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of $g$ at $f(2,1)$ correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, determinant, jacobian, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy),$ where $x>0,y>0.$ Let $g$ be the inverse of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $f(2,1)$. Then the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of $g$ at $f(2,1)$ is equal to...............?

**Solution:**
Let $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$,where $f_1(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $f_2(x,y)=2xy$,then the Jocobian of the matrix is,$Jf=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2x & -2y \\
2y & 2x 
\end{bmatrix}$,then $Jf(2,1)=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -2 \\
2 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}$,$det(Jf(2,1))=det \begin{bmatrix}
4 & -2 \\
2 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}=20\neq 0$,then by Inverse function theorem $det (Jg(2,1))=det (Jf^{-1}(2,1))=\frac{1}{det((Jf(2,1)))}=1/20$

Is my Solution correct?Please suggest anyother method by which it can be tackled also check whether I applied the Inverse function theorem correctly

Answer (score 0):

Mostly.

$f(2,1)=(3,4)$  so you want $\det(\mathrm J_g(3,4)) = \det(\mathrm J_{f^{-1}}(3,4))$

But otherwise, yes, that is: $\det(\mathrm J_f(2,1))^{-1}=1/20$.